# InvalidArgument=Value of '4' is not valid for 'index'

Tags: c#, listview

I am trying to replace the text of column 5 of my listView but everytime I try to do it, I keep getting this error: `InvalidArgument=Value of '4' is not valid for 'index'.`

I am trying to replace any items under column 5 which have no text, basically those which are blank with the word No.

Here's my code:

```
foreach (ListViewItem i in listView1.Items)
{
    if (i.SubItems[4].Text == " ")
    {
        i.SubItems[4].Text = i.SubItems[4].Text.Replace(" ", "No");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged and checked the Count property of the SubItems collection ?

Comment: You need to post more code, like the structure of SubItems or ListViewItems.  where is the declaration of each objects SUBITEMS array?  Are you sure that each array is actually of size 5?

Also you should change'

    i.SubItems[4].Text = i.SubItems[4].Text.Replace(" ", "No"); 

to this 

    i.SubItems[4].Text = "No";

Comment: @jordan.peoples Did not work, same error

Comment: did you post more code? the fix i suggested above was just to downsize your code, not to fix the bug.  POST MORE OF YOUR CODE

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that the sub-items start with the second column, where the first column is the list view item's value. So Column #5 would be `SubItem[3]` not 4.